# how to get the maximum from a list of records with multiple similar documents in Monogodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

im new to Mongodb, i have collection which looks like this;

```
empno   points    date_saved

6000    80        "2021-09-18T08:25:49.319Z"
5000    60        "2021-09-18T08:25:49.319Z"
7000    70        "2021-09-18T08:25:49.319Z"
6000    60        "2021-09-17T08:25:49.319Z"
```

I want to pass a specific empno for example 6000 to the query and I need to get the max points he has in the table. Where the output should be

```
80
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- filter the empno
- group by null (all table 1 group, because all documents are from 1 employ after the filter)
- take the max
- project to keep only 1 field

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3vGn4f6YLbW)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "empno": {
        "$eq": 6000
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "max-points": {
        "$max": "$points"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "max-points": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works well. Is there a way to get the max-points value only?

Comment: yes i removed any extra fields on the update now returns `{"max-points": 80}`, MongoDB documentation is very good with examples.